# Hts? (Winter Bash 2014, PPCG edition)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

*apologizes for terrible pun in title*

I recently received an email from a Community Manager from Stack Exchange:

> Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to **all sites that choose to participate**. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra features to keep things fresh and exciting.

So, my question to you is: **Hats or no hats?**

Personally, I welcome our colorful headcloth overlords. This site is all about having fun; shouldn't we be the *most* suited to this event? Of course, though, you can vote for whatever you want, and only the overall results will be considered for the final decision.

So, what do you think? Upvote whichever position you agree with, and by December 1st, assuming it's not a close tie, our decision will be sent in to the SE team.

Oh, and if you're *puzzle*d (ha, ha) as to what this whole "hat" thing is about, [here's the FAQ for last year's Winter Bash.](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq)

Regardless of what we end up choosing, happy winter!

Comment: What is Winter Bash?

Comment: It's the party celebrating the time of year when you turn into Snowbolt.

Comment: Should this be [featured]?

Comment: You are hoping to get a "Post a Meta question with a pun on 2014-11-18"-hat, aren't you? ;)

Comment: @ProgramFOX I don't get the pun ;(

Comment: @professorfish The pun in the title, or the pun in my message? (there was no pun in my message)

Comment: @ProgramFOX the one in the title of the question

Comment: @professorfish Well, this site is about golfing, so golfed "Hats" is "Hts".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Yes!

More colorful headcloths for us!

*Author note: This has my upvote.*

Comment: We want fun!!! #YOLO

Comment: I feel kinda silly wearing winter hats in the middle of summer, but whatever.

Comment: Well, the vote is 31 vs 0 after 2 days. I highly doubt that'll change any time soon, so colorful headcloths for us it is!

Answer (score -10):

## No!

I don't want hats. I hate fun!

Comment: I had fun once. It was awful.

Comment: @Martin But was it the communicable kind? ;-)

Comment: I want to downvote this answer as a stupid answer even though I don't want hats, because the reason I don't want hats isn't that I hate fun but that I see them as pointless. When you present options for voting, you should either be neutral (this is the option, with no pros or cons) or make a genuine effort to play devil's advocate. You've set this up as a "Heads I win, tails you lose" vote. Asking people to vote on false dichotomies doesn't give a real representation of community opinion, and for those people who find some SE sites hostile it will serve to reinforce that perception.